# How to read two pair of files in same directory and send to same camel exchange?

Tags: apache-camel

I need to read pair of files with same name but different extension in same directory say for example 
1. abc.json
2. abc.signed

above files should be sent same camel exchange, where value from abc.signed is used to validate the abc.json file.

Please advise !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **pollenrich** to read both kind of file in a single route and then perform validation within that route.

```
<pollEnrich timeout="5000"><simple>file://pathto//yourfile?antInclude=*.json&amp;noop=true</simple>
</pollEnrich>
<setHeader headerName="JSON">
<simple>${body}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

By doing so, you can able to get both json and signed values.